# Ursina не правильно показывает 3D модель

Tags: python, ursina

Я делал 3Д модель дерева в блэндере и когда я загрузил эту модель в Ursina некоторые грани остались белыми, хотя в блэндере все отображалось нормально, модель '.obj' и файл '.mtl'. Вот как в блэндер:

[image: Вот как в блэндер:]

А вот как в игре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код игры:

```
from ursina import *
from random import uniform
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

myplayerpos=[0,10,0]
otherplayerpos=[10,10,0]

app=Ursina()

Sky()

player=FirstPersonController(position=(0,10,0))
otherplayer=Entity(model='cube', scale=(1,3,1), texture="brick", collider='box', position=otherplayerpos)
ground=Entity(model='plane', scale=(100, 1, 100), color=color.lime, texture="white_cube",
    texture_scale=(100, 100), collider='box',position=myplayerpos)

tree=Entity(model='Tree2', position=(10,10,10))

app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

1.указывайте расширение файла (всегда)

```
tree=Entity(model='Tree2.obj', position=(10,10,10))
```

2.можете сделать текстуру и задать её

```
tree=Entity(model='Tree2.obj', position=(10,10,10), texture = "НАЗВАНИЕ.png")
```

3.попробуйте если всё это не работает изменять '       ' на "     "

**Я не профи но делал что либо на ursina engine**